# Google AdMob Earning Money From Rewarded Ads

Tags: admob, interstitial, rewardedvideoad

I recently developed a mobile game which uses Google AdMob. Clicking on interstitial ads increases my earnings but watching a rewarded video makes no change. Is there a threshold for rewarded videos? Unity Ads gives money after 5000 rewarded videos watched so is it same case with Google AdMob? I couldn't find any information about it on the official website of AdMob.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't a programming question. It's about the financial T&Cs of some company's service.

Comment: Is there anyone to answer it?

Comment: Well, I wrote the responsible people at google and they said that If your video just watched you don't earn any money interstitial ads just looks like the other ads I mean If someone click to view ad then you earn money. This is really bad...

Comment: @KemalCanÖZÇELİK Thank you for informing me. It is really bad that we don't earn money from watched videos.